# Play video from library and record video by camera at same time - Objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am building an app which can play the video from library and at the same record a video using camera. Is it possible to watch a video and record a video simultaneously?

Comment: You mean camera video in one window and the libray video in another?

Comment: No, in the same view controller but with two different UIViews(Objective C) @BlueVoodoo

Answer (score 0):

Here a sample in link iPhone media gallery for both image and video support [here](https://github.com/yfujiki/FGallery-with-Video)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.