# Play the video from URL and record video by camera at same time - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to build an app which can play a video from URL and also record the video using the front camera simultaneously. I tried it but the video stops playing when camera starts capturing and vice versa. Please help me out. Thanks in Advance!!
Here is my code, I'm using DIYCam(using AVFoundation) framework which records perfectly and using AVPlayer for playing

```
- (IBAction)startRecording:(id)sender {
self.cam = [[DIYCam alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300)];
self.cam.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.f, 0.f);
self.cam.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300);
self.cam.delegate       = self;
[self.cam setupWithOptions:nil];
[self.cam setCamMode:DIYAVModeVideo];
self.cam.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[self.cam captureVideoStart];
```

}

-(void)playVideo
{

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"responcevideo"
                                     withExtension:@"mp4"
                                      subdirectory:nil];
AVPlayer *_avPlayer;
_avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url] ;
```

AVPlayerLayer *_avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:_avPlayer];

```
_avPlayerLayer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:_avPlayerLayer];

[_avPlayer play];
```

}

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: record video by camera...while playing a video? curious what the purpose is?

Comment: that's my question too...

Comment: @Andrews : please dont ask same question multiple times.Better wait for an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269172/play-video-from-library-and-record-video-by-camera-at-same-time-objective-c

Comment: @bryanmac i added the code. please take a look.

Comment: @LithuT.V its a kind of app that captures user's expression while watching a video.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run recording and playing video on separate threads.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks, will do that in the future.